# Oracle VirtualBox - Unable to update to Windows 10

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox 5 and my virtual Windows offered an Update to Windows 10 today, but it stops saying:

> VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
>   The display manufacturer hasn't made your display compatible with Windows 10. Check with the manufacturer for support.

The Windows Update only offers to "*Check out new PCs*". There is no way to force the Update.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [Microsoft Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to force the update. Execute it and choose "Upgrade this computer now". This allows you to upgrade to Windows 10 using Oracle VirtualBox. Please double check you have the latest VirtualBox Guest Additions installed, to avoid errors.